# Getting "No overload matches this call" error when using useQuery with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-query

I have a **type** problem with typescript.

I have the following API:

```
export const clientAPI ={
//...
  getOptions: async (myParam: number) =>
    get<{ options: Options[]; courses: any[] }>(`/courses?myParam=${myParam}`)().then((result) => {
      localStorage.setItem('result', JSON.stringify(result))
      return result
    }),
//...
}
```

Assuming that *get* method is the following:

```
const get =
  <T>(url: string) =>
    () => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
      return fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          ...(token ? { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } : {}),
        },
      }).then((res) => parseResponse<T>(res))
    }
```

And I call *getOptions* like follows:

```
useQuery("result", clientAPIs.getOptions(value as number));
```

What I need is to put the response in *local storage* in order to access it with a dynamic select, that depends of few events. When I change a value I call an API that returns dynamically the options, so this is why I need to put them in local storage.
The problem is that the way I call it (last code above) gives some type errors, even if it compiles and actually stores the response as I wish.

The error is the following:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(queryKey: "result", options?: UseQueryOptions<unknown, unknown, unknown, "result"> | undefined): UseQueryResult<unknown, unknown>', gave the following error.
    Type 'Promise<Options[]>' has no properties in common with type 'UseQueryOptions<unknown, unknown, unknown, "result">'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(queryKey: "result", queryFn: QueryFunction<unknown, "result">, options?: UseQueryOptions<unknown, unknown, unknown, "result"> | undefined): UseQueryResult<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Promise<Options[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryFunction<unknown, "result">'.
      Type 'Promise<Options[]>' provides no match for the signature '(context: QueryFunctionContext<"result", any>): unknown'.ts(2769)
(property) getOptions: (country: string) => Promise<Options[]>
```

That's more like a warning, but I'd like to know how to solve it.

Comment: useQuery comes from `reeact-query`. I import it like this: `import { useQuery } from "react-query";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing a promise to your `useQuery` call (`clientAPIs.getOptions(...)` returns a promise) but it actually expects a function as the fetcher parameter.

To fix the issue, you can simply modify the second parameter to be a function.

```js
useQuery("result", () => clientAPIs.getOptions(value as number));
```

Comment: I tried this solution tanstack query v4 and ts v4.x. I still get this linter warning with the following code `useQuery<UsersResponse>('users', () => fetchUsers());`. Don't know why.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't that an extra pair of parenthesis before the `.then()`? you are already passing the type and the url, don't know about that parenthesis after that

```
...
get<{ options: Options[]; courses: any[] }>(`/courses?myParam=${myParam}`)().then((result) => { ... }
```

Comment: Thant's coming from the **get** method man. Look closer to it